# How to hide submenu for anonymous user Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a main menu like this:

```
Menu item 1:
Menu item 2: 
     Submenu item 2.1
     Submenu item 2.2
     Submenu item 2.3
Menu item 3:
Menu item 4:
```

I want to hide submenu items for anonymous user and show those only to authenticated user.

menu created by superfish and I am using drupal 7

Comment: How is the menu generated? Put a conditional inside the generation and don't generate if non-user.

Comment: Thanks chris! Menu created by superfish module (https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish)

Comment: I am very new to drupal, Let me try to do that if-else, I will let you know if I require further help. Thanks chris!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that only logged in users can reach those pages you should try the node access module. Otherwise an anonymous user can still reach those pages (even if its not showing in the sub menu).

Through the module you can make access for that page only for logged in users. For anonymous users who try to visit the page it will show "access denied" or your custom page. It should also hide the link from the menus when it is an anonymous user, since they don't have permission to view the page!